# Can villagers sleep in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Let's say that I move a villager from the overworld to the nether and place a bed, would he sleep on it?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this `minecraft-bedrock-edition`, or is it also/primarily a `minecraft` question?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude it was supposed to be a question about both versions of Minecraft (Bedrock and Java)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Beds placed in the nether will explode when you try to use them. Fortunately for villagers, this rule doesn't apply to them and they can sleep in beds as usual when in the nether.

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager):

> Villagers can sleep in the Nether or the End, if the Overworld's time is correct.

It can also be seen in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/bs2jgp/villagers_can_safely_sleep_in_nether_and_end/):

[image]

Comment: It can also be used to make a working day/night indicator in the Nether!

Comment: Note about my previous comment: It was for MCJava. I do not know if it's the same in MCBE, which this question is apparently about.

Comment: @FabianRöling well, “working” is a bit subjective, given that there's no day/night cycle in the nether; on my server, they're quite desynced from the Overworld day cycle, too…